# If vibranium is the strongest metal on earth, then why did Captain America's shield dent when Peggy Carter shot it?

Tags: marvel, captain-america, vibranium

In Captain America: The First Avenger, Peggy is mad at Steve so she pulls the trigger on her gun three times and the shield dents. Why is that? Also, in Captain America: The Winter Soldier, Steve gets shot at like, a million times and his shield doesn't dent. I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Strongest metal on earth doesn't necessary mean it's impervious to damage even from softer materials. For instance, liquid water is much softer than solid metals like brass and aluminum. Yet pure waterjets at high enough pressures can cut sheet metal without any abrasives added: http://d2n4wb9orp1vta.cloudfront.net/resources/images/cdn/cms/Test%20strip%201.jpg

Comment: "Fury of a woman scorned" and all that... :P

Comment: [Here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137443/37440)'s a somewhat relevant question on Physics Stackexchange.

Comment: @JBentley I was hoping it was going to discuss the physics of a material like vibranium...

Answer (score 26):

### It probably didn't

Here's what the shield looks like in the first scene you mention:

[image]

Those don't really look like dents to me. They look darker than the shield, not merely shadowed. I suspect they are residue from the tracks of the bullets themselves, rather than dents on the shield.

Here's another scene from slightly later on:

[image]

It's more clear that these are simply scuff marks, rather than dents. **Note that the paint is [not invulnerable](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53008/is-the-paint-on-captain-americas-shield-also-invulnerable).**

Here's an image from [a promotional poster](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjVl7uX3MHMAhVD5yYKHW0yAnQQjhwIBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffansided.com%2F2013%2F10%2F23%2Fcaptain-america-winter-soldier-marvel-releases-first-poster-film%2F&psig=AFQjCNHP5hODsYzPYqOhIUBq4Pupyja5cQ&ust=1462495956186589) for *The Winter Soldier*:

[image]

**Note that there are plenty of residue marks here, which seems to make it unlikely that Captain America's shield was pristine during *The Winter Soldier*.**

A better question might be why there are a few rather obvious scratches on the shield.

Comment: It's reproduced the machining marks from the mould pretty well, you could argue that those were scratches (not that I can spot them) were also in the mould.

Comment: I want to know how they managed to create the star pattern after the shield was already forged, and add details to the star later.

Answer (score 16):

Captain America's shield did not get dented when Peggy Carter shot at it.

[image: Screen shot of the shield after being shot]

Here is a link to a video on YouTube.  It starts at the 1:02 mark and shows Peggy shooting the shield and then the above screen shot.  There seems to be two scuff marks but no dents.

[Video of shooting shield scene](https://youtu.be/_11Fx44iCJg?t=1m2s)